# Mahapps.Metro Dialog not showing in Command.Execute

Tags: mahapps.metro

I want to show a "loading" dialog while doing some work. When I trigger the job with a button click event,  it is working (the main window is grayed out and the dialog is shown modal).

XAML:

```
<Button Click="ClickButton" ... />
```

The View:

```
private void ClickButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var dialog = this.Resources["MyDialog"];
   this.ShowMetroDialogAsync(dialog as BaseMetroDialog);

   ... do the work
}
```

But when I use a command

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
```

and call the dialog in the commands Execute method

```
public async void Execute(object parameter)
{
   MainWindow metroWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
   var dialog = metroWindow.Resources["MyDialog"];
   await this.ShowMetroDialogAsync(dialog as BaseMetroDialog);

   ... do the work
}
```

the main window is only grayed out and no dialog is shown.

Comment: It seems you forgot to say await... `await this.ShowMetroDialogAsync(dialog as BaseMetroDialog);`

Comment: @punker76 Copy paste error, my mistake. In the code I have "await". I updated the question